# Internationalization using subfolders

Tags: seo, internationalization, ruby-on-rails

I'm internationalizing a Rails application using their standard i18n gem. I've set it up so that the language appears as a subfolder in the URL, ex. www.mysite.com/en, www.mysite.com/zh, www.mysite.com/en/pages ...

My concern is that the link 'juice' attributed to the pre-internationalization site, www.mysite.com/pages, is going to be diluted by the insertion of the language into the URL, www.mysite.com/en/pages.

Is this the case?

How do I mitigate this?

The site owner would like to see all of the English site URLs remain as is and that the country subfolder, /zh/, only be present for the new language version.

Answer (score 2):

You can do either -- leave English without a language code, or redirect the English pages to be under /en/. Language is handled on a per-URL basis, you can set it up however you want, it can even be via querystring parameter.